# how to get values sent by location.replace(URL)

Tags: javascript

In my JavaScript function I do like this in order to redirect parameters to servlet:

```
var ids1=document.getElementById("projet").value;
document.location.href("http://localhost:8080/Opc_Web_App/ServletAffectation?ids1="+ids1);
```

and in the servlet I do the following to get Value:

```
String idprojet= request.getParameter("ids1");
System.out.println("le projet selectionné est :" +idprojet);
```

the problem that i didn't have the result of System.out.print in my screen; so in other terms the servlet didn't get the parameter.

I can not see the problem until now.
Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you meant `location.replace` instead `location.href` on the first code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
String idprojet= request.getParameter("ids1");
```

Comment: I am sorry i have changed before to ids1 but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

What Matthew said or change the JavaScript to:

```
var projet=document.getElementById("projet").value;
document.location.href("http://localhost:8080/Opc_Web_App/ServletAffectation?projet="+projet);
```